# Is there any benefit of using a web server when deploying a rust web application?

Tags: rust

There are tutorials which teach us to deploy rust web application using nginx, apache etc.

There are other [tutorials](https://engineering.deptagency.com/create-a-rust-web-service-from-zero-to-cloud) and [posts](https://www.reddit.com/r/rust/comments/nocmvl/how_to_properly_deploy_rust_application/) which teach us to run the executable without any third party web server.

Given both are possible, is there any benefit of using a third party web server instead of running the executable on its own.

Comment: not specific to rust, but its usually easier to set up SSL, manage the domain level routing, etc. when hosting behind a web server.

Comment: If you are deploying your application on cloud infrastructure behind a load balancer then you probably don't need a proxy (nor even TLS).

Comment: I think this question is a little too broad though. There are lots of ways to deploy a web application with lots of trade-offs, none of which are Rust-related.

Comment: In general, if you have a good reason to use a standalone web server, you already know it (or your ops team already knows it), so you don't need to ask a question here. Those reasons are often one-off, bespoke, site-specific things (f/e, I've been somewhere we had a web server plugin that knew how to parse a particular application-generated cookie to allow SSO) that random people on Stack Overflow won't know anything about.